# How to use information from a ComboBox in another one?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a `UserForm` with `comboboxes` and `textboxes`. I have two `combobox` that are working together. In the first one you choose the right sheet and in the second you choose the right column in the selected sheet.

My problem is that even though my code is working, the second `combobox` doesn't use the moving information from the first one. It always displays the columns from the first sheet whatever my choice. So how do I get the data from the first one to use it in the second one?

Here's my code:

````
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim I As Long
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    For I = 7 To Sheets.Count
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(I).Name
    Next
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ActiveSheet.Name

    
 Me.ComboBox2.Clear
 
Dim j As Integer
Dim puits As String

j = 3

Do While Worksheets(ComboBox1.Text).Cells(1, j).Value <> ""
     Me.ComboBox2.AddItem Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Text).Cells(1, j).Value
     j = j + 3
Loop

End Sub```

EDIT
[USF is to automate the change of the selected cell in this screenshort, same tables on different sheets][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bbQG.png
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Combobox_Change`-Event. This Example shows what I mean:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long, i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)
    
    lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For i = 1 To lCol
        UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem ws.Cells(1, i).Value
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next ws
End Sub
```

When I select the Sheet, I change the first Combobox, which triggers the `Change`-Event. And I then populate the second Combobox according to the selected sheet.

**EDIT**
You could insert a CommandButton and use code like the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)
    Set rng = ws.Range(UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value)
    
    rng.Value = "Your Date"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.

I change to this and it still doesn't work I don't get why...

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim j As Integer
Dim puits As String
Dim feuille As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text)
j = 3

Do While Sheets(ws).Cells(1, j).Value <> ""
     Me.ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets(ws).Cells(1, j).Value
     j = j + 3
Loop
End Sub

Comment: @Bastien You need to use `Combobox1_Change()`. You want to trigger the event if the first combobox changes, not the second

Comment: Thank you so much it's working and I understand ahah. I have though another question for my next (last) step... I have another using button using DatePicker (selection of the line) and a textbox to imput data in the selected line x selected column, so I have to use the changes of all boxes, where do I put these instructions?

Comment: @Bastien I don't really understand the question. Could you calrify?

Comment: Sorry. The purpose of my UF is to input data in spesific cells in an already existing table, on a spesific selected sheet. So I would choose the sheet, then the column then the line (date) to get this cell. Now on my UF I'm able to choose all these information, I just need to extract the information so when I input the new data on the textbox it goes on the right cell. But it's beyond my VBA skills and I'm not sure exactly how I should do it, I'm learning by myself and I miss some basics. My guess is making a commandButton so send the new data from the texbox to the cell, but how?

Comment: How do you specify the line the data should be inserted to? So to clarify, you first select the sheet from the first combobox, then the range from the second combobox and then you select a date?

Comment: But so I don't get the same issue as before where the code was in the wrong place, I should put it in the CommandButton right?

Comment: @Bastien Yes. Once you selected everything in your UserForm you can make a CommandButton, which writes the Data to the selected sheet and range. See the Edit

Comment: Oh I get it! But the value in colomn and line comboboxes actually refers to the name of the colum and the date for the line so if I put that in range(), will it work?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your data (or some mock data), so I know, what you are referring to?

Comment: I edited my post with the screen of the data table. I have several sheets with similar structure, the USF is to automate the input of data for other users